# jenkins master and slave artifact path and deploy to artifactory

Tags: git, jenkins, artifactory, artifacts, jfrog-cli

**1, i am using jenkins master and slave concept, i m running jobs on slave machine. My question is where does the final artifact is stored by default, whether in master or slave machine and what is the path?**

2, [i should deploy the final artifacts that is tar file to artifactory server as shown in image, what can i mention in artifacts to deploy box and also Remote File Location box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKbmA.png)

please click this link for image

**i should deploy the final artifacts that is tar file to artifactory server as shown in image, what can i mention in artifacts to deploy box and also Remote File Location box **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding **artifact storage**, Jenkins will keep its copies with the job history, always in its master node.

For a job configured on Jenkins' root, the archive is located on the following folder `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<your_job_name>/builds/<build_number>/archive`.

On that folder, the file will be kept in the same relative path as it had on the workspace. For example, if during the pipeline the artifact was available in `$WORKSPACE/outputs/mybinaryfile`, in the jenkins master node it will be available in `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<your_job_name>/builds/<build_number>/archive/outputs/mybinaryfile`

Now, regarding the configuration on the **artifact deployer plugin**, I believe that the path in 'Artifacts to deploy' is probably wrong. `/*.tar` will look for tar files on the root of the filesystem (/)

If what you want is to archive all tar files on the folder where the jenkins pipeline is executed (the workspace), you can refer to that using the $WORKSPACE environment variable or by prepending a dot (`.`) to your current path

Both `$WORKSPACE/*.tar`  `./*.tar` should work